# JQuery: manually clicking on a checkbox does not change 'checked' attribute on page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have come across a rather strange behaviour. I have two pages (lets call them **page A** and **page B**), both pages contain the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a > img.id-provider, #signup-button').click(function(e){
        if (!$('#chk-agree').attr('checked')) {
            alert('Please accept our terms and conditions before continuing');
        }
        else {
            alert('ok');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

The page is viewable here: http://jsfiddle.net/SrRAS/

On page B, the behaviour is as expected, i.e. a warning is issued when the checkbox is not checked before the signup button is clicked.

However, on page A, the warning is always shown, if even the checkbox has been manually clicked to make it checked.

Here is the FF console output (for both pages), when I was trying to understand what was going on:

```
>>> $('#chk-agree').attr('checked')
undefined
>>> $('input#chk-agree').attr('checked')
undefined
```

Eventually, on page A, I decided to programatically set the checked attribute (instead of manually clicking it - as a normal user would):

```
>>> $("input#chk-agree").click()
jQuery(input#chk-agree, input#chk-agree)
>>> $("input#chk-agree").attr('checked')
"checked"
```

When I then clicked the signup button on **page A**, it worked as expected (displayed an 'ok' message). However, when I manually unchecked the checkbox on **page A**, it still continued to display an 'ok' message. So it seems that for some reason, on **page A**, manually clicking on the checkbox does not toggle the 'checked' attribute.

I have two questions:

1. Why is manually checking the checkbox not toggling the checkbox 'checked' attribute
2. What would cause the code to work as expected on one page and not another?

**[[Edit]]**

```
I have also tried the following check instead of the one shown in my snippet above:

if (!$(this).is(':checked')/*!$('#chk-agree').attr('checked')*/) {
   ...
}else {
   ...
}
```

Now, at least the behaviour is consistent across both pages in that, **none of the pages (A or B)** seem to acknowledge when the checkbox is manually clicked - what on earth is going on?!

**[[Edit2]]**

The markup of the page that is not working is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SrRAS/

I will be very interested in finding out what is causing it not to work on this page.

Comment: Please add the relevant pageA/pageB HTML. Without it this question is mot likely referring to a very localized issue. Maybe there is checkboxes with the same id on the page or something else which result in the behavior.

Comment: As a side-note (not solving your issue), As per the [**prop() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/): `According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all, even if the attribute has no value or an empty string value. The preferred cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to check for a "truthy" value on the element's property using one of the following` **:** `if (elem.checked)`, `if($(elem).prop("checked"))` or `if($(elem).is(":checked"))`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I am trying to pare/strip down the page that is not working to post a barebones markup with the problem to jsfiddle. At the moment, I suspect that a dropdown() plugin is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: The markup is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/SrRAS/

Comment: Well thet markup on that jsfiddle is broken, specifically, you are not closing your input tag:

     <label id="form-signin-remember" class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="chk-agree"><small>Remember me</small>*should close input here!*</label>

Comment: ID's should really be unique and not used.. If I run `$('[id=chk-agree]')` in the console I get two elements..

Comment: Wasted 1 hour ...no Words .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this version of your [JsFiddle with Fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/SrRAS/16/) It contains two changes. checkboxes with unique IDs and correct jquery code for checked elements

```
if ($('input#chk-agree').is(':checked')) {
        alert('ok');
    }
    else {
        alert('Please accept our terms and conditions before continuing');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be caused by duplicate `chk-agree` Ids. I wonder if this might have been a copy/paste error: the first `chk-agree` checkbox is used as part of your "Remember Me" functionality.

The consequence of this duplication is that `$('input#chk-agree').attr('checked')` evaluates to `undefined`, which is falsey in Javascript.

The solution here is to rename one of the two checkboxes with a different Id. For example, if I rename the first checkbox (line 70 of the jsFiddle) to `chk-remember-me`, things work fine and I get the 'OK' message.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup, I'd still be willing to bet that you must have some small difference between page A and Page B. Have you tried backing up the files, and replace the markup from A with that from B? As there is no sane reason why the exact same code on two separate HTML pages would work differently.

For me, this markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="testbox"  value="check me"/> 
<input type="button" id="testbutton" value="click me" />
```

and this js:

```
$("#testbutton").click(function() {
    if ($("#testbox").attr("checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("Not Checked");
    }
});
```

Works just fine in every browser I've tried. Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gsxfz/

```
 $('#signup-button').click(function (e) { <-- its an '<a>'
   if (!$('#chk-agree:checked').length) {// <--check for the length of checked checkboxes
     alert('Please accept our terms and conditions before continuing');
   } else {
     alert('ok');
   }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gsxfz/

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following changes

## Page A

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="chk-agree-pageA"> // checkbox ID

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success signup" id="pageA">Sign In</button>
```

## Page B

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-agree-pageB"> // checkbox ID

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success signup" id="pageB">Sign In</button>
```

### Finally the script

```
$('button.signup').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($('input#chk-agree-'+id).is(':checked')) {
           alert('ok');
        }
        else {
            alert('Please accept our terms and conditions before continuing');

        }
    });    
});
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SrRAS/25/

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will alert you that you have duplicate ids on the page

if($('input#chk-agree').size()>1) {
    alert('you have duplicate ids on this page');
}


// this will fix your problem in jsfiddle:

if (!$('input#chk-agree')[1].checked) {

    alert('Please accept our terms and conditions before continuing');
}
else {
        alert('ok');
}

// but removing the first duplicate id is the right fix :-)
```